# Solr - Nearest Match - Does this functionality exist?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, fingerprinting, audio-fingerprinting

Can Solr give you a nearest match when comparing "fingerprint" type data stored in the Solr datastore. For example,

```
   eJyFk0uyJSEIBbcEyEeWAwj7X8JzfDvKnuTAJIojWACwGB4QeM  
   HWCw0vLHlB8IWeF6hf4PNC2QunX3inWvDCO9WsF7heGHrhvYV3qvPEu-  
   87s9ELLi_8J9VzknReEH1h-BOKRULBwyZiEulgQZZr5a6OS8tqCo00cd  
   p86ymhoxZrbtQdgUxQvX5sIlF_2gUGQUDbM_ZoC28DDkpKNCHVkKCgpd  
   OHf-wweX9adQycnWtUoDjABumQwbJOXSZNur08Ew4ra8lxnMNuveIem6  
   LVLQKsIRLAe4gbj5Uxl96RpdOQ_Noz7f5pObz3_WqvEytYVsa6P707Jz  
   j4Oa7BVgpbKX5tS_qntcB9G--1tc7ZDU1HamuDI6q07vNpQTFx22avyR
```

Can it find this record if it was presented with something extremely similar? And can it provide back a confidence score?

Answer (score 1):

one straighforward approach could be to use [a fuzzy search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches), and pick the first hit (by score), then you need to check whether the hit is good a match or not, maybe by testing  you could find some good rule of thumbs.

But not sure if perf would be an issue with such long tokens. Use Lucene4.0 where fuzzy perf is much improved.

Answer (score 0):

You may try experimenting with [Ngram filter factory.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory)  You may pick a min/max gram size that is consistent with a matching/similar finger print.

If you have a tight range of minGramSize and maxGramSize, you can match documents with similar fingerprint without having to iterate over false positives.